# Http / php (функция header("Location:...")

Tags: header, php, http

Почему в php файле отправив такой заголовок:

```
header("Location: https://www.google.com.ua/");
```

даже после того, когда я его удалил и обновил страницу с которой его отправлял , у меня при открытии в браузере этой страницы открывается google?

Comment: Потому что браузер помнит, что в прошлый раз эта страница пересылала его на гугл и не тратит времени на отправление запроса. Если как-нибудь не выставили код 301, то должно быстро пройти.

Comment: так что мне сделать то?
это весь код который я там написал.
Как сделать чтобы браузер забыл? Или как предотвращать это?

Comment: @hil400k, кэш браузера сбросить да и делов.

Comment: @hil400k, ctrl+shift+del

Answer (score 1):

Ответ из комментариев:

---

Потому что браузер помнит, что в прошлый раз эта страница пересылала его на Google и не тратит времени на отправление запроса. Если как-нибудь не выставили код 301, то должно быстро пройти.

А вообще, вы можете отчистить кэш браузера (в большинстве браузеров Ctrl+F5).